# Color of quoted text in email editor

Tags: thunderbird, colors

I managed to configure Thunderbird to work well with dark color scheme.

Only thing left (I hope) is that when I hit Reply to a message, the original text is quoted in blue, which is unreadable.

[image: editing reply - quote not readable on dark gray background]

Can I change this color as well?  (I'm only interested in plain-text messages as I don't send out HTML.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question at Mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=513670). You can do this by changing your `userContent.css` file.

The code you'd need to add is

```
span[_moz_quote=true] {
    color: pink ! important;
}
```

changing 'pink' to whatever color you prefer.

On Windows XP, you'd find the file in `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\chrome` (the `chrome` sub-folder does not exist by default); see [developer.m.o](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_Configuration_Files) for location on other OSes.

Comment: Nice. The location on Linux is `$HOME/.thunderbird/086vp1vb.default/chrome` and you may need to create the `chrome` sub-directory.

Comment: To find and test out various other possibilities, use "Tools" > "Developer Tools" > "Developer Toolbox". You can change pretty much anything about any window this way and you will see the change immediately (to keep it, you will need to add it to the .css file).

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply, even tried the "Developer Tools" comment above.  Changes don't affect anything.

Comment: make sure to edit/create the file `userContent.css` (not `userChrome.css`!)

Answer (score 1):

Note that customization via `userContent.css` and `userChrome.css` is deprecated. Thus, applied as is, the solution described in the accepted answer will not work with recent versions of Thunderbird.

As a work-around, one can set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` in the configuration editor.

I do not know whether there exists a more up-to-date solution to the problem described in this question.